# Get container view's parent viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicontainerview

I have an UIViewController called `MainVC` contains an UITableViewController called `TableVC` by using a container, and I'm trying to get the parent view controller of `TableVC` by using the following code inside of the itself:`let parentVC = self.parent as! MainVC`, but I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Then I double checked if `self.parent` is nil, as expected, it is. After that, I use the following code inside of `MainVC`:`self.childViewControllers[0] as! TableVC` to make sure `TableVC` is a child view of `MainVC`, and the code works just fine. So, my question is, how can I get the parent view of a container view?

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to get the parent View Controller *before* the TableVC has actually been added to it? Where in your code are you calling let parentVC = self.parent as! MainVC ?

Comment: @DonMag It is in func ViewDidLoad()

Comment: @DonMag I just moved it into func ViewWillAppear(), and it worked! Thanks alot!

Comment: Did you configure these two controllers via storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: OK - *probably* what's happening: ViewDidLoad() runs when your TableVC loads... at that point, it is not actually a child of anything... so you cannot get its parent. Try putting `let parentVC = self.parent` in viewDidAppear()... edit: whoops, your comment beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it's the reason that you need the reference of MainVC, but if you need execute some function or change some value in MainVC you should use Delegates, you can find more information about how can use it [here](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef#.b9djzg13h)

Other option is that you create a reference in UITableViewController of type MainVC and set it when you present the UITableViewController

[image]

[image]

Comment: The reason why i need  the reference of MainVC is that I have a gesture recognizer to detect tap gesture in order to dismiss the keyboard when touch outside of the keyboard. and it will need two targets, one is the TableView itself, and the other one is the MainVC

Answer (score 0):

`.superview` access on any `UIView` subclass gives you the parent.
If you know the hierarchy of your view controller stack, `.superview` should help you out.

Comment: ViewControllers don't have superviews